# UL/LI CSS menu not aligning properly

Tags: html, image, list, css

I am having issues getting my menu to align properly. The images are all spaced far away from each other even when they should be closer. I am new to using Ul and Li and am not sure how to fix this. Ideally I would have the images across the whole screen with no space on the right or left and just a thin space between each image, but instead, there is a large space. I am unsure if this is something in the Ul Li tags or if there is something I can do with margin.

Could someone please advise me. I am including a jsfiddle to show what it currently looks like. https://jsfiddle.net/f1bctqzn/ is what I am currently getting. How do I these lines to touch their respective sides of the screen and still have a small space between the rest.

```
<li class="header"><a href="/menu/kale-grain-bowls"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/T4ZAaK3.png" class ="kale-grain-bowls"></a></li>
<li class="header"><a href="/menu/kids-real-meals"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/T4ZAaK3.png" class ="kids-real-meals"></a></li>
```

Comment: First of all you images are all gray box, not sure how can i debug. Secondly you have margin added which will definetly add some space on all the four sides.

Comment: Yeah, they are supposed to be gray boxes, for now, I am just trying to get them in position properly at this point. Is there a way to put margin on differently? I also have tried changing the value of margin and haven't seen a change in the result.

Answer (score 1):

Add `padding: 0` to your `ul` and `margin: 1px` (or something) to `li`
Also, add `width: 100%` to `img`

Comment: instead of max-width? or in addition?

Comment: doesn't matter if you have width: 100% :)

Comment: well now it is displaying as one solid line

Comment: did you add margin to li?

Comment: my bad no I did not. That fixed it in this context. There is a little more space in between it and the div below it in the full scope but i can work on that thank you!

Comment: Cool, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f1bctqzn/1/)
To add space betwwen the `li` items, don't add the `margin` property to the `ul`, but add a margin to the `li` items (I used the 2px you had set for the `ul`). To add a margin only between the `li` items, I used

```
li.header{
  margin-left:2px;
}
li.header:first-child{
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adjusted the margins and used a `flexbox` to adjust the images across the whole screen.

Check it out and let me know your feedback. Thanks!

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul.toplist {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
li.header {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: 1px;
}
img.kale-grain-bowls,
img.salads,
img.burgers-sandwiches,
img.sides,
img.smoothies-milkshakes,
img.kids-real-meals {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="toplist">
  <li class="header">
    <a href="/menu/kale-grain-bowls">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/T4ZAaK3.png" class="kale-grain-bowls">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="header">
    <a href="/menu/salads">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/T4ZAaK3.png" class="salads">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="header">
    <a href="/menu/burgers-sandwiches">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/T4ZAaK3.png" class="burgers-sandwiches">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="header">
    <a href="/menu/sides">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/T4ZAaK3.png" class="sides">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="header">
    <a href="/menu/smoothies-shakes">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/T4ZAaK3.png" class="smoothies-milkshakes">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="header">
    <a href="/menu/kids-real-meals">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/T4ZAaK3.png" class="kids-real-meals">
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```